# Evaluate a logical operator from a string in python

Tags: python

I have a few python strings parsed from a file where there are several hundred conditions that i need to evaluate. How would you experts out there recommend I evaluate these conditions? For example...

```
["20", "<=", "17.5"] # false
["15", ">=", "18.5"] # false
["20", "==", "20"] # true
["beta", "==", "beta"] # true
["beta", "!=", "beta"] # false
```

I wasn't sure if there were any tricks to resolving these equations, or if i should do some sort of if else like...

```
op = parts[1]
if op == '<=':
    return op[0] <= op[2]
elif op == '>=':
    return op[0] >= op[2]
elif op == '==':
    return op[0] == op[2]
elif op == '!=':
    return op[0] != op[2]
```

Comment: If it's just these 4 operations I don't see anything wrong with your if/elif chain.

Comment: What is the correct answer for `["20", "<=", "7.5"]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `eval()` function:

```
parts = ["20", "<=", "17.5"]
print(eval(' '.join(parts)))  # False
```